# How to Get device token of all registered devices (APNS)?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I have a iPhone Application which is Hosted in Apple Store, Recently due to a DB Failure(Corrupt) all the registered device token for the Application are corrupted now I am unable to Push notifications to devices.

Is there any way to get the registered Device Token once again  from Apple Servers?

Comment: No, you app is the only one how kan push the token to you server. This is way I always push my token every time the app starts. I just register for push notifications again and when I receive the token I push it to our server.  This also makes sure that I the token changed in between launch the change is pushed directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think Apple keep the record, as tokens received on phone are directly sent to your own server in your App. And there's also no related information stored in your push notification certificate.

Your best bet is to have an App version update and upload the token again.